# Wireless connection issues

Tags: wireless-networking

HP laptop says it is connected to the net but then says it cannot find router or modem. This is a wireless system. Took the laptop to a friends house and it connected to his wireless system with no problems. My son's HP laptop has no problems with the home system. It works just great but my wife's will not. This wireless system came from AT&T. The affected laptop has Vista. When I hit the net key it says that explorer cannot display this page, when I hit diagnose it says that my modem or router is not available. I have tried resetting everything many times to no avail. On the computer screen icon it shows that I am connected to the net.

Comment: How far away are you, physically, from your wireless router when you have these problems?  If you move closer (like sitting right next to it), does it work?

Answer (score 0):

since you know that your laptop is good at your friends house, it's the internet at your house that's the problem.

Call your internet provider and have them sort it out.

Comment: You can't be sure of that, sometimes it is just the combination that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

troublshoot and isolate if the problem is the router or modem or your broadband connetion. If you have a spare modem or router, use that to connect to your broadband connection to see if you get connection. If so, check phone filter. Also check cable connections. What does device manager tell you about your network connections icons?

Calling at&t tech support will help you troubleshoot the issue and at the same time use their tools from their end to check the connection.